# 16-bit texture through PyOpenGL

Tags: python, opengl, pyopengl

I am trying to create a 16-bit texture in PyOpenGL using below statement.

```
img_data = cv2.imread("Texture.png",cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB16UI, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, img_data)
```

But it throws invalid operation with traceback a sbelow:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\gurubhat\PycharmProjects\OpenGL\TextureSample.py", line 106, in <module>
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB16UI, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, img_data)
  File "src\latebind.pyx", line 39, in OpenGL_accelerate.latebind.LateBind.__call__
  File "src\wrapper.pyx", line 318, in OpenGL_accelerate.wrapper.Wrapper.__call__
  File "src\wrapper.pyx", line 311, in OpenGL_accelerate.wrapper.Wrapper.__call__
  File "C:\Users\gurubhat\PycharmProjects\VENV\venv\Lib\site-packages\OpenGL\platform\baseplatform.py", line 415, in __call__
    return self( *args, **named )
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "src\errorchecker.pyx", line 58, in OpenGL_accelerate.errorchecker._ErrorChecker.glCheckError
OpenGL.error.GLError: GLError(
    err = 1282,
    description = b'invalid operation',
    baseOperation = glTexImage2D,
```

16-bit textures are not supported on Window? (or may be graphics card?)

Loading of 8-bit images like below works perfectly fine (I guess GL_RGB stores textures internlly in float32 format)

```
img_data = cv2.imread("8bitimage.png",cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, img_data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get an invalid operation error, because your internal format is integral (`GL_RGB16UI`), but the specified format of texture is not (`GL_RGB`). See [`glTexImage2D`](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexImage2D.xhtml) and the [OpenGL 4.6 API Specification](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.core.pdf#page=233&zoom=100,168,708)

> An INVALID_OPERATION error is generated if the internal format is integer and format is not one of the integer formats listed in table 8.8, or if the internal format is not integer and format is an integer format.

Change the *internal format* to a floating point format (`GL_RGB16`/`GL_RGB`)

```py
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB16, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, img_data)
```

or the *format* to an integer format  (`GL_RGB16UI`/`GL_RGB_INTEGER`)

```py
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB16UI, width, height, 0, GL_RGB_INTEGER, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, img_data)
```

In the shader, a sampler of type `sampler2D` must be used for the floating point texture and a sampler of type `usampler2D` must be used for the unsigned integral texture. Also see [Sampler (GLSL)](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Sampler_(GLSL)).

---

> I guess GL_RGB stores textures internally in float32 format

No it does not. The texture usually has 8 bits per channel internally as long as no sized internal format is specified. e.g.: `GL_RGBA16`. See [`glTexImage2D`](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexImage2D.xhtml).

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer.It cleared a lot of things and infact using GL_RGB_INTEGER for format and usampler2D in shader code solved it(as I needed 16bit values i shader). But in the working example I provided format (not internal format) is specified as GL_RGB (float) but the data is unsigned byte , not sure how this is handled properly.

Comment: @bsguru If the data type of the source image is unsigned byte, you have to use `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE` instead of `GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT`. But why do you need than a 16bit internal format?

Comment: @Rabbit76  I provided that example just to show '8-bit works 16-bit doesnt'. I needed 16-bit numbers in shader code. What I am not understanding is in the working example , the  data is 8-bit unsigned byte and format is speicified is GL_RGB (which is float as per your answer) , so how this handled properly?

Comment: @bsguru Sorry, but I don't get that. You can't turn 8bits into 16bits.